# What can I use to glue acrylic sheet together?

Tags: glass

What can I use to glue acrylic sheet (Plexiglas) together?

Also is it easier to cut and shape Plexiglass or real glass?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If by Plexiglass you mean acrylic sheets, use acrylic cement. It formulated especially for that. Old way to dissolve small pieces of plastic in dichloroethan, but it is more toxic. Cut plastic easier than glass.

Answer (score 3):

It's not always easier to cut plexiglass than glass.

I recently had to cut some (very expensive, stupid panicvirus) plexi for a project and had a dickens of a time with the score-and-snap method because the plexi was too flexible. I ended up cutting it with a circular saw.<sup>*</sup>

If you have very stiff plexi, you can probably do the score-and-snap quite easily (I've done that before), just like you would with glass. If it's flexible plexi, it will be more difficult.

If you need complex shapes, especially curves, then the plexi may be easier to work with because you can use regular wood working tools to cut & shape it - just be prepared for the smell of melted plastic and work in a well ventilated area. You *can* cut complex shapes, even curves, into glass but it may be more work to do so - score-and-snap many short lines, then "sand" or grind the glass into the curved shape with an appropriate, hard sanding block, probably something specifically designed for working with glass.

---

<sup>*</sup> Make sure you wear eye protection if you're going to do this!! I had little pieces of plexi flying everywhere. I used a 6.25" battery powered circular saw with a home made track saw and just took my time to ensure that the cut was nice and clean. Man-o-man did the little pieces of plexi fly! I had several hit me in the face, though none cut/scratched me. I had a couple of pieces bounce off the safety glasses too. (Note that my saw seems to be designed to throw as much dust into the operators face as possible, YMMV.)

Comment: "It's not always easier to cut plexiglass than glass."  When and why or how easier to cut glass?

Comment: When you say flexible plexiglass are you sure you are not referring to polycarbonate? It is much harder to score and snap (it can be bent to a 90 in a “break” without cracking where poly would shatter. They are different.

Comment: @user263983 glass is always (to my knowledge) a simple score and snap. Much easier than the process I described above.

Comment: @EdBeal you may be right - it might have been polycarbonate that I had instead of acrylic. It's been a few months since I worked on that project, I used about 98% of the sheet I purchased, and the label has long since been in the trash, so I cannot confirm one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I bought something called Poly Bonder from [Fire Mountain Gems and Beads](https://www.firemountaingems.com). I have not used it yet but have used something similar in the past.  It creates an invisible bond between 2 pieces of acrylic that fit perfectly together.  You might want to try it on 2 or more flat pieces first.  It alters the surface of the acrylic so it melds together to create a permanent bond.  After it sets, you can sand the shape and you will not see the bond.  I made several multi-colored blocks that way and the color changes show where the bonds are but they are not visible like glue can be and the pieces must fit together perfectly with no gaps.  The bonder changes the chemical composition of the surfaces of the pieces to be joined. The plastic top of the bottle of the stuff I used previously cracked and the bonder dried out and became unusable.  It was one of many things that I did not pack after a fire in my basement 2 years ago so I don't have the name of it or remember where I got it years before that.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! This is a nice answer, but it's hard to read as one giant wall of text. If you could insert a couple of paragraph breaks (hit `<enter>` twice), that would make it much more readable. Also, providing both a phone & web site for a product recommendation starts to border on looking like spam. You do start by saying it's a product you bought, so you're probably good there.